# can I make a separate dataframe for edgelist attributes between root/terminal vertices in igraph? (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes, root, igraph

here is the head of the data I am working with:

```
    motherinst                     inst      time      dist     speed
2  20080713_235233_es_0_JWC 20080714_163628_es_0_XKK 0.6971644 1.4921751 2.1403490
3  20080714_163628_es_0_XKK 20080715_160601_es_0_LAL 0.9788542 2.3070819 2.3569210
7  20080715_160601_es_0_LAL 20080716_153449_es_1_UOW 0.9783333 2.8299124 2.8925851
8  20080715_160601_es_1_CUA 20080716_153449_es_2_GOC 0.9783333 0.4322427 0.4418154
9  20080715_160601_es_2_KOE 20080716_153449_es_3_POU 0.9783333 4.1533350 4.2453168
10 20080715_160601_es_2_KOE 20080716_153449_es_4_SOA 0.9783333 2.1224896 2.1694954
```

What I want to do is be able to specify a root and terminal vertex (either by # or "inst") and then make a separate dataframe with every single value of "dist" running down in rows between all the vertices in that root-terminal pair. Dist is stored as an edge attribute. So, essentially, I'm trying to make a dataframe of the total distance between all of those vertices, with each of their distances stored down the rows.

i.e.

```
    JWC-XKK
1      0.69
2    .....
3    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some approach:

```
foo %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(1:2), ~str_sub(., start = -3)) %>% 
  select(motherinst, inst, weight = dist) %>% 
  mutate(weight = weight * 1.5)-> foo_graph

foo_graph

  motherinst inst   weight
1        JWC  XKK 2.238263
2        XKK  LAL 3.460623
3        LAL  UOW 4.244869
4        CUA  GOC 0.648364
5        KOE  POU 6.230003
6        KOE  SOA 3.183734
```

Multiplication by 1.5 is just to make the width of the vertices more visual

```
library(igraph)

foo_plot <- graph.data.frame(foo_graph, directed = F)

plot(foo_plot, layout=layout_in_circle, edge.width = E(foo_plot)$weight, vertex.size = 30)
```

Plot:

[image]